# Why is the explicit template instantiation not working?

Tags: c++, templates

I declared a class in a header and code file.

SharedResourceManager.h

```
#ifndef SharedResourceManager_H_
#define SharedResourceManager_H_

#include <mutex>

namespace find_object {

    template <class T>
    class SharedResourceManager {
        public:
            SharedResourceManager();
            SharedResourceManager(T* resource);
            ~SharedResourceManager();
            T* checkOutResource() const;
            void checkInResource() const;
            void updateResource(T* resource);
        private:
            T* _resource;
            std::mutex lock;
    };
    extern template class SharedResourceManager<std::string>;
}
#endif
```

SharedResourceManager.cpp

```
#include "SharedResourceManager.h"

using namespace find_object;


template <class T>
SharedResourceManager<T>::SharedResourceManager() 
{
    this->_detector = NULL;
}

template <class T>
SharedResourceManager<T>::SharedResourceManager(T* resource)
{
    this->_resource = resource;
}

template <class T>
SharedResourceManager<T>::~SharedResourceManager()
{
    delete this->_resource;
}

template <class T>
T* SharedResourceManager<T>::checkOutResource() const
{
    this->lock.lock(); //Lock the detector until released with checkInDetector
    return this->_resource;
}

template <class T>
void SharedResourceManager<T>::checkInResource() const
{
    this->lock.unlock();
}

template <class T>
void SharedResourceManager<T>::updateResource(T* resource) {
    this->lock.lock();
    delete this->_resource;
    this->_resource = resource;
    this->lock.unlock();
}

namespace find_object {
    template class SharedResourceManager<std::string>;
}
```

example.cpp

```
#include "SharedResourceManager.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
namespace find_object {

    void func() {
        std::string orig = "resource";
        SharedResourceManager<std::string> srm(&orig);
        std::string* resource = srm.checkOutResource();
        cout << "Shared Resource Manager Created" << *resource << endl;
        srm.checkInResource();
    }
}

int main() {
    find_object::func();
    return 1;
}
```

I am trying to use this templated class in example.cpp. I tried to explicitly instantiate the template with the class I needed, but I still get the following linker error when compiling with: `g++ example.cpp`

```
/tmp/ccfssejJ.o: In function `find_object::func()':
example.cpp:(.text+0x56): undefined reference to `find_object::SharedResourceManager<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::SharedResourceManager(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*)'
example.cpp:(.text+0x62): undefined reference to `find_object::SharedResourceManager<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::checkOutResource() const'
example.cpp:(.text+0xac): undefined reference to `find_object::SharedResourceManager<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::checkInResource() const'
example.cpp:(.text+0xb8): undefined reference to `find_object::SharedResourceManager<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::~SharedResourceManager()'
example.cpp:(.text+0xff): undefined reference to `find_object::SharedResourceManager<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::~SharedResourceManager()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am building with catkin build. Why am I getting this error?

Comment: A [mcve] would help. (Something short that we can compile a reproduce the error.)

Comment: Did you link `SharedResourceManager.cpp` to whatever file is using the template?

Comment: I'm not sure how to make a file to reproduce the error. I'm editing an open source project to fix a race condition. The file that I am using this resource manager in is 1800 lines. I'll see what I can do though.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I added example usage that produces the same error.

Comment: *"error when compiling with: `g++ example.cpp`"* Well, duh. Of course the explicit instantiation had no effect, you didn't compile the file that contains it!

Comment: For some reason I thought that .cpp files with the same name as a header were implicitly compiled.... It looks like the issue with the original code was that I needed to add the new SharedResourceManager.cpp file to the list of source files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start with, the explicit instantiation in the source file **must be** in the same namespace that the template appears in, a using directive does not cut it. So you need to amend your source file into this:

```
namespace find_object {
    template class SharedResourceManager<Feature2D>;
}
```

Beyond that, you'll likely want an explicit template instantiation *declaration* in the header:

```
template <class T>
class SharedResourceManager {
  // as before
};

// Need to add this
extern template class SharedResourceManager<Feature2D>;
```

This instructs the compiler not to implicitly instantiate the class template, since the instantiation is elsewhere.